# Object Detection on Cloud using React-Native Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, object-detection, object-detection-api, google-vision

Complete React Native noobie here. I am trying to make an app in React Native Expo that will send an image to a cloud platform (still haven't decided on which one). The cloud will then recognize the objects in the image, put them in a square, and then return the image to the phone. I've been researching for days and I found APIs like [Google Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision), and I found that Google has a module for  [multiple object detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer). This is exactly what I need to do but I don't know how to implement it. I've been looking online and found a [project](https://blog.jscrambler.com/create-a-react-native-image-recognition-app-with-google-vision-api/#) that seems to be similar but is lacking object detection it rather has image labeling which is not what I need.

1. Are there any 3rd party APIs I can use in my project that can be used in i.e. Firebase?
2. How do I connect my app with i.e. Firebase? Can someone give me an example?
3. The picture needs to be manipulated on the cloud thus the squares need to be added on the cloud. Is this possible? I've checked out Google Vision but it seems to just return a JSON file (might be wrong)?
4. What would be the best cloud service that already has the API I need?

Comment: Not familiar with the rest but about the 3, the GoogleApi will return a json and you will need to parse it and manipulate as you want.